# 表示させたいhtmlファイルが表示できない

Tags: python, html, django

upload_saveメソッドにアクセスした時、base.htmlだけ が表示されてしまいます。view.py に

```
def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")

    photo_obj.image = files[0]
    photo_obj.save()

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)
```

と書き、本当はupload_saveメソッドにアクセスした時、photo.htmlを表示させたいです。

photo.htmlには

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="page-header">{{ photos.title }}</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{ photos.image }}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:upload' photo.id %}">一括アップ</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

と書きました。グーグルの検証を使ってElementsを見てみるとやはりbase.htmlだけが表示されています。どう直せば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 表示てのはブラウザでの表示ですか？生成したphoto.htmlはどの様になっているでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`base.html` の内容が書かれていないのでなんともですが`base.html`に`{% block body %}{% endblock %}`が書かれていないんじゃないかと。